# how to intall expr lib java

Tags: installation, expression, java

how to install the Expr lib of java (about Evaluating math expressions)
[here in readme](http://github.com/darius/expr#installing-it) I can unterstand the frase "To install, put expr.jar in your classpath. (You'll need to create it first by running make, if you downloaded this from GitHub.)
To try it out, put the expr directory in your classpath."

how I run "make"?? please help

Comment: GitHub will contain the source code that needs to be compiled (through 'make'). I'm sure the source has instructions on how to compile it.

Comment: in cmd? that is the command? sould iI download github? I am prety new on this

Comment: If you're having trouble with this, I'd recommend you just use Eclipse. You can import the project directly from Github if you have the [EGit plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/). Adding something to your classpath in Eclipse is as simple as right-clicking on it, then clicking "Add to classpath".

Comment: @Hassan I want to add just expr.jar as lib on my project,not a new project

Comment: What I meant was that you can use Eclipse for your project. Is this what you're doing already?

Comment: I use eclipse for my project and i want to add expr lib to use it for expr evaluating. do you see the link and of how to install? have you any idea???

Comment: Ohh I see. I'm guessing you're on Windows, which means make isn't pre-installed. One thing you could try is to just add the source directory to your classpath. You can also get [make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm).

Comment: @hassan I can unterstand "make"! is a command prompt commant or not? i install it from your link but nothing

Comment: Yes, it is a command line program. Open a terminal, type `cd C:\some_path\expr` to get to the directory where the file called "makefile" is located. Then simply type "make". It should compile if you have everything else set up (it also requires javac, so install that if you don't have it).

Comment: @Hassan all ok! After install [make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) , I have to add the make.exe directory to Path variable on windows. like say [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx)
now make commad works, thank you very much.

Comment: Okay, glad I could help. I posted an answer, I'd appreciate it if you could upvote / accept if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install make by getting it from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm).

Make is a command line program. Open a terminal, type cd C:\some_path\expr to get to the directory where the file called "makefile" is located. Then simply type "make". It should compile if you have everything else set up (it also requires javac, so install that if you don't have it).